# Accessing global variable in static library

Tags: c

I have a custom LLVM compiler that places a global variable (glob_var) into the data section. When I execute the following *main.c* program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern unsigned char glob_var[];

int main() {
    printf("%x\n", glob_var[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The content is printed. Now I am trying to write a static library *lib.c* accessing this variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern unsigned char glob_var[];

static void __attribute__((constructor)) ctor() {

    printf("%x\n", glob_var[0]);
}
```

I am compiling:

```
clang -c -Wall -o lib.o lib.c
llvm-ar rc lib.a lib.o
clang -c -o main.o main.c
clang -o main.out -Wl,--whole-archive lib.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive main.o
```

And I get:

```
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: glob_var 
>>> referenced by lib.c
>>>               lib.o:(ctor) in archive lib.a
```

for the last command.

Note that the glob_var variable gets created during the compilation of main.c. When I disassemble main.o, the glob_var is in the data section:

```
Disassembly of section .data:
0000000000000000 <glob_var>:
```

Comment: `clang -c -fPIE -Wall -o lib.o lib.c` creates an [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file), not a [shared library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries).

Comment: Maybe clang did some tricks, but if glob_var is declared extern in all files, it is not supposed to be defined by any of these files... I suggest to remove the "extern" word in lib.c.

Comment: Who could possibly know how your custom compiler breaks things? Post an example everyone can reproduce.

Answer (score -1):

Actually the variable `glob_var` is defined in no module. You could have got the same diagnostic for "main.o". (As I tried to reproduce your issue, I got the error just for "main.o".)

Please decide which module should define the variable, that means to provide the actual space for it. In your example, remove `extern` in either "main.c" or "lib.c".

Concerning your disassembly: Since the object module "main.o" is not linked, it just shows that it knows about a variable `glob_var`. But it has no allocation for it.

---

Anyway, the correct<sup>TM</sup> way to declare and define globals is to use a header file, which "transports" the knowledge about them. All sources that need to know these globals include the header file. And finally one source file defines the globals, and it includes the header file, too. This way you let the compiler check that declarations and definitions match.

In your case this file declares the variable. The preprocessor conditional construction is called a "header guard", please research the usage yourself, if you don't know it.

```c
/* lib.h */

#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

extern unsigned char glob_var[];

#endif
```

The main source will include the header file.

```c
/* main.c */

#include <stdio.h>

#include "lib.h"

int main() {
    printf("%x\n", glob_var[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I have decided to let the library define the variable, because it seems that the variable belongs to the library. Additionally, I have set the size of the variable in its definition.

```c
/* lib.c */

#include <stdio.h>

#include "lib.h"

#define GLOB_VAR_SIZE 10

unsigned char glob_var[GLOB_VAR_SIZE];

static void __attribute__((constructor)) ctor() {

    printf("%x\n", glob_var[0]);
}
```

Comment: Better solution is to have header file with extern declaration

Comment: @0___________ Like this?